# Some elements from JSON object passed to MVC controller are NULL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass a JSON object to my MVC controller action via POST. The controller action is called but some elements of the object are NULL. The 'ArticleKey' is there but the 'MeasureDefinitions' are NULL (see below).

Here is the object which I am trying to parse (it gets appended with more values by the user):

```
    var articleValues = [
        {
            'ArticleKey': {
                'ArticleNo': 'ArticleNo',
                'CustomerName': 'CustomerName',
            },
            'MeasureDefinitions  ': [
                {
                    'DisplayIndex': 0,
                    'MeasureType': 'MeasureType',
                    'Percentage': 99.99,
                    'OriginalPercentage': 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

My model looks like this:

```
    public class ArticleValuesModel
    {
        [Key]
        public ArticleKey ArticleKey { get; set; }
        public List<MeasureDefinition> MeasureDefinitions { get; set; }
        public string ArticleDescription { get; set; }
        public bool AddToList { get; set; }
    }

    public class ArticleKey
    {
        public string ArticleNo { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }

    public class MeasureDefinition
    {
        public long DisplayIndex { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public string MeasureType { get; set; }
        public double Percentage { get; set; }
        public double OriginalPercentage { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is my controller action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateArticleValuesJson(List<Gui.Models.ArticleValuesModel> modelList)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Here is my Ajax POST:

```
        $('#btnSaveArticleValues').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ArticleList/UpdateArticleValuesJson",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "JSON",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(articleValues),
                success: function() {
                    console.log("Saved");
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
        });
```

Can you please help me to make the 'MeasureDefinitions' list accessible in my controller?

Comment: There are extra space in your JSOn, try to remove them.

Comment: That did the job. Thank you! I am so blind *facepalm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the extra spaces in my JSON object like indicated by the_lotus did help to resolve the problem.